# parametrization of the hyperboloid of two sheets

Tags: differential-geometry

Find the parametrization for the hyperboloid of two sheets${(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3}; -x^2-y^2+z^2=1$.

Ok so I saw two answers for this question: $x(u,v)=(\sinh u \cos v, \sinh u \sin v, \cosh u)$ and $x=(u,v)= (\cosh u \sinh v, \sinh v, \cosh u \cosh v)$. I'm pretty sure the first one is the correct one. But I'm confused on how to parametrize.

So what I think is,

$$x^2+y^2-z^2=-1$$

$$x^2+y^2=z^2-1$$

$$r^2=z^2-1$$

$$r=\sqrt{z^2-1}$$

So, $x=r\cos v$=$\sqrt{z^2-1}\cos v$, $y=r\sin v= \sqrt{z^2-1}\sin v$, and $z= \sqrt{z^2-1}$.

Clearly I know this isn't right but I'm not sure how to go from here. I know we need to get the partial derivative and I guess somehow that gets us the missing part. Can someone help please.

Comment: $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ or $-1$?

Comment: -1...sorry about that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are many parametrizations, so no such thing as **the** parametrization.

You have $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = z^2$.  If you write $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ (so you can take 
$x = r \cos(v)$, $y = r\sin(v)$), then $r^2 + 1 = z^2$.
Now since $\cosh^2(u) - \sinh^2(u) = 1$, you could take $z = \cosh(u)$, $r = \sinh(u)$, and thus 
$$ \eqalign{x &= \sinh(u) \cos(v)\cr
            y &= \sinh(u) \sin(v)\cr
           z  &= \cosh(u)\cr}$$
However,this is **not** a good parametrization at $u=0$ (corresponding to the single point $(x,y,z) = (0,0,1)$.

Now let's try a different way.  Write the equation as $t^2 - y^2 = 1$ where
$t^2 = z^2 - x^2$.  We can take $y = \sinh(v)$ (note that this ranges over
$\mathbb R$ as $v$ does), and then $t^2 = \cosh^2(v)$.  If we choose the
positive $t$ (and we can), we have $t = \cosh(v)$.  Now 
$(z/t)^2 - (x/t)^2 = 1$.  For the sheet with $z > 0$ we can take
$z/t = \cosh(u)$ and $x/t = \sinh(u)$.  As $u$ ranges over $\mathbb R$, 
we get all possible $(x,z)$ pairs with $z > 0$.  So we have

$$
\eqalign{
x &= \sinh(u) \cosh(v)\cr
y &= \sinh(v)\cr
z &= \cosh(u) \cosh(v)\cr}
$$

This parametrization is better because it maps ${\mathbb R}^2$ one-to-one onto one sheet.

Comment: Wow yes this makes more sense. Thank you so much.

Comment: the parametrization $\phi_1(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1})$ and $\phi_2(x,y)=(x,y,-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+1})$, defined in $\mathbb{R}^2 ,$ is  one-to-one onto one sheet, right?  @RobertIsrael

Comment: Posted date: $\approx \pi$ $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Is it possible to parameterize an n -hyperboloid like this ?  Similar to the parameterization for n-sphere in n variables.

Comment: what if z is negative how can we generalise the parameterisation for both $z > 0$ and $z < 0$?

Comment: @R_Squared There are two sheets and their union is not connected, so you can't get both in one continuous parametrization.  For the other sheet take $z = - \cosh(u) \cosh(v)$ with the same $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2):

If $x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2-z^2/c^2=1$ is the hyperboloid then putting $z=c.\tanɸ$ it reduces to $x^2/a^2-y^2/b^2=\sec^2ɸ$ or,$x^2/(a.\secɸ)^2-y^2/(b.\secɸ)²=1$ which again has parametric representation $x=a.\secɸ.\secɵ$, $y=b.\secɸ.\tanɵ$. So $x=a.\secɸ.\secɵ$,$y=b.\secɸ.\tanɵ$, $z=c.\tanɸ$ is the required parametrization