# Finding a parametrization of a curve from cartesian equations

Tags: differential-geometry, parametric, parametrization

I'm in need of some help to address this problem.

*Let $C$ be a curve given by two equations:*

$x^2+y^2-z^2-1=0$,

$x^2-y^2-z^2-1=0$

*Express the curve by means of parametric equations.*

Any ideas on how to work on it?

Comment: You may want to look up the notion of a hyperboloid.
see e.g. 
1) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158042/deriving-parameterization-for-hyperboloid 
2) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697245/parametrization-of-the-hyperboloid-of-two-sheets

Comment: My answer was not complete. I edited to add what was missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtract the two equations. We get $y=0$

Plug in the first
$$x^2-z^2=1$$
A parametrization is
$$(x=\cosh t,y=0,z=\sinh t); (x=-\cosh t , y=0, z=-\sinh t)$$
In the image below the two surfaces and their intersection.

---

$$...$$

[image]

Comment: I'm grateful! This makes perfect sense. Thank very much Mr. Raffaele

Comment: @PierreCarre True! Thank you. $(-\cosh t , 0, -\sinh t)$ is missing

Answer (score 1):

If you take the first restriction and plug it into the second, you get

$$
x^2-y^2-(x^2+y^2-1) - 1 =0 \Leftrightarrow -2y^2 = 0 \Leftrightarrow y=0
$$

So, any point on the curve satisfies $y=0$ and $x^2-z^2 = 1$ and you can consider two separate parametrizations:

$$
(\sqrt{t^2+1}, 0, t), t\in \mathbb{R}
$$

$$
(- \sqrt{t^2+1}, 0, t), t\in \mathbb{R}
$$

Comment: FWIW, here's an [interactive 3D plot, using Sage](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJyN0M0KwjAMAOD7niK3diwb-8GL0HfwLk66ruiwW2dXdd3TW4WJgoMdEkIgH0lGBIcwIVhgcOeGkhEdTmhJGFRd7Zs0LhCKMNj5uml71YjGHnulbVHTscwjV-bx5CNjLMUA_BB-JaGVNowYWRME3XM_7BikyeYFRn_FeJVYqZtcRyreVjWH911bf-2SeDJSdr9kPps9N7yV1jRiVvfD1Vhq_QOyECH1DzzM8mdDLi5kGYjXC8lw1g8aPgGBxoHI&lang=sage)